# getting files off a server using terminal

Tags: c++, vim, copy

I'm using vim on the terminal app on my mac and I'm attempting to save files to my computer that are on my college's server. I am already linked into to the schools server is there a way to copy the files to my home directory and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sshd running on the server, you can run the following from the terminal:

```
scp -r you@server:/home/you/some/place/* .
```

The above will copy all files on the server located in /home/you/some/place to the current directory that you are running the command from.